# Is there a way to add tooltips to a (responsive) html image map?

Tags: javascript, html, responsive

I have a custom map (an image), and i need to show country names when the mouse cursor is over the countries areas.

I'm using an HTML map. My image which uses the HTML map is in a modal that you can open with button click. i have tried tooltipster (http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) and Responsive HTML Image Maps jquery plugin (https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer), but i can't get it to show tooltips exactly where i want and this might be due to responsiveness issues as the image takes the height of the modal while the image size is bigger than that, and i created the map based on the real image size.

Here is my map code:

```
 <img src="<?php the_field('home__map_lightbox_image'); ?>" class="locations-map-full" alt="<?php the_field('home__map_lightbox_title'); ?>" usemap="#map">
                    <map name="map" id="locations-map">
                           <area shape="circle" coords="596, 408, 10" title="Libye" class="tooltip"/>
<area shape="circle" coords="508, 361, 16" title="Tunisie" class="tooltip" />
<area shape="circle" coords="457, 374, 7" title="Algerie" class="tooltip" />
<area shape="circle" coords="406, 360, 16" alt="Maroc" class="tooltip" />
                    </map>
```

So, my question is: is this the right way to do it ? am i on the right way or should i use something other than HTML maps ?

Comment: please add an online  link to your image map or else the code to re-produce it

Comment: @NikosM. done..i can't share the link since i'm working on localhost.

Comment: yes i think you would need to use something else than an image-map since the responsive nature can alter the coords given. Try somethign like this jquery plugin http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html

Comment: The plugin you provided is based on image maps as well, but my question is whether to use something different like some svg maps etc. I will give it a try though, it seems better than the plugin i'm using.

Comment: good if it solves your problem consider accepting the answer. Furthermore you can try svg maps but i dont know how easy it would be to add tooltips to them that wiould be better than an image-map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a javascript plugin like this: [jquery.responsive-image-maps](http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html) that dynamicaly re-computes the coordinates of the image map on `window.load` and `window.resize`. Then everything should work fine.

If you like you can try responsive svg image maps as well (they are easier to be made responsive, but I am not sure about the tooltips added).

For example see this [create-responsive-svg-image-maps](https://www.creativebloq.com/netmag/create-responsive-svg-image-maps-51411831)

Here is [example of adding tooltipster tooltips to an svg map](https://journocode.com/2016/08/02/svg-tooltips/)

Answer (score 1):

**Working snippet - vanilla JS**

Although not perfect, this approach works:

**Note:** I've changed the first image map to appear in the center

```js
function myFunc (el) {

  var tooltip = document.getElementById('myTooltip');
  tooltip.style.display = 'block';
  tooltip.innerHTML = el.title;
}

function myFuncHide(el) {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById('myTooltip');
  tooltip.style.display = 'none';
  tooltip.innerHTML = '';
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    /*console.log(e.pageX);
    console.log(e.pageY);*/
    document.getElementById('myTooltip').style.left = (e.pageX+5)+"px";
      document.getElementById('myTooltip').style.top = (e.pageY+5)+"px";
 
});
```

```css
#myTooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <img src="https://images.icanvas.com/list-square/abstract-photography-1.jpg" class="locations-map-full" width="600" height="600" alt="" usemap="#map">
                    <map name="map" id="locations-map">
                           <area shape="circle" coords="596, 408, 10" title="Libye" class="tooltip"/>
<area shape="circle" coords="300, 300, 100" title="Tunisie" class="tooltip" onmouseover="myFunc(this)" onmouseout="myFuncHide(this)"/>
<area shape="circle" coords="457, 374, 7" title="Algerie" onmouseover="myFunc(this)" class="tooltip" />
<area shape="circle" onmouseover="myFunc(this)" coords="406, 360, 16" alt="Maroc" class="tooltip" />
                    </map>
                    
                    
<div id="myTooltip" />
```

Comment: The problem is that the default title also shows up next to the tooltip, it looks like a duplicate, and it's not responsive. It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You can leave the title empty and use another custom attribute for the tooltip

Comment: It is responsive as the tooltip is based on mouse position, not <area /> position. <area /> is used only to set text and show the tooltip div. Although hidden, the tooltip is always next to your pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom hotspot to your map using Taggd script which is responsive and easy to use.
https://timseverien.github.io/taggd/v3/